# Robot Framework: how to encode string using ascii?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a keyword:

```
Verify Payment Method Field
Element Text Should Be    ${paymentMethodValueField}     PDF-lasku sähköpostiin
```

here is the logs:

```
Step 3 Fields verification :: OK: Display Customer Information fie... | FAIL |
The text of element '//div/span' should have been 'PDF-lasku s?hk?postiin' but in fact it was 'PDF-lasku s?hk?postiin'.
```

I need to write something like that, but I don't know how:

```
 PDF-lasku s[ascii symbol]hk[ascii symbol]postiin
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: This is strange. As a native Finn I have used Robot against several Finnish webpages and scandinavian letters have never been a problem. Have you checked if your browser and OS localizations are correct?

Comment: I'm from Ukraine, and I'm using Google chrome Version 49.0.2623.87, Windows 8;
Maybe it's localizations bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably convert the whole thing to one format or another, then evaluate?  Or is it important that ASCII characters are located in certain parts of the string?  If not and you simply want to verify what is returned is exactly what you expect, I'd probably use Encode String to Bytes for simplicity, perhaps even the encoding/decoding keyword would serve your needs if the ASCII is important.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Encode%20String%20To%20Bytes

By using the above you could set it to ignore the characters that cannot be converted or replace them with a known character that you provide.  Simply get the text first, then perform whatever manipulation you want and evaluate.

The alternative with regard to decoding/encoding if ASCII location is important is:

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Bytes

Comment: yes, it's possible solution! thanks